# SSL certificate thawte, verisign or geotrust

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to decide which from the list of ssl certificate providers (thawte, verisign or geotrust) should i chose that correspond for the following criteria

SSL certificate:

- installed for one domain
- usefull for unlimited subdomains
- installed on multiple machines

Comment: wildcard domain ssl is what you want, all the 3 are very good and do have it.

Comment: Any of those providers can supply your requirements, so what is your question?

Comment: Well of those 3, I'd prefer GeoTrust, but my reasons may not apply to you. As all 3 deliver what you want, what is it you want to know about them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter your criteria at http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-wizard.html and it will let you compare each provider's certificates

Answer (score 1):

Just go for the cheapest option, your users won't notice anyway.

The only difference is green address bar (a.k.a. Extended validation), but last time I looked they costed the same everywhere.

Comment: i was hoping someone was @ exactly the same spot not so long time ago, and would say hey this and that offered me the best price so go 4 them :> because there aren't any big differences anyhow.